# How to generate, export to word docx file?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, docx, export-to-word

I am trying to generate a `docx` in jasper report. I have this code:

```
JRDocxExporter exporter = new JRDocxExporter();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();    
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, baos);
exporter.exportReport();
```

How do I write the report out to file? Most of the examples I have seen are all around using servlets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the parameter `JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME` to specify the file and remove the parameter `JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM`.

```
JRDocxExporter exporter = new JRDocxExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "myreport.docx");
exporter.exportReport();
```

Comment: That works perfectly thanks - i searched everywhere and couldn't find anything which did this.

Comment: `setParameter` deprecated :(

Answer (score 8):

> [JRExporterParameter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRExporterParameter.html) is **deprecated** since jasper version 5.6

The current way since this version would be:

```
JRDocxExporter export = new JRDocxExporter();
export.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
export.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(new File("path/toMy/report.docx")));

SimpleDocxReportConfiguration config = new SimpleDocxReportConfiguration();
//config.setFlexibleRowHeight(true); //Set desired configuration

export.setConfiguration(config);            
export.exportReport();
```